# Output inside function scope doesn't match that of it's parent

Tags: c++

College student.  I can't use String class, haven't learned pointers.

I cout inside the cardCopy() function to make sure strCopy() is doing it's job and everything looks fine in there, but once I check the the output in deckCopy is doesn't match.

If you compile you'll see what I mean.

Help?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

/******************************************************************************
 * STRINGS
 ******************************************************************************/

int strSize(char str[])
{
    int size = 0;
    while (str[size] != '\0')
    {
        size++;
    }

    return size;
}

/**
 * Empty out a string
 * 
 * @param str
 */
void strEmpty(char str[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strSize(str); i++)
    {
        str[i] = 0;
    }
}

/**
 * Copy a string.
 * 
 * @param from
 * @param to
 */
void strCopy(char from[], char to[], int len)
{        
    //cout << "From: " << from << ", " << strSize(from) << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        to[i] = from[i];
    }

    //cout << "To: " << to << ", " << strSize(to) << endl;
}

/**
 * Append one string to the end of another
 * 
 * @param from
 * @param to
 */
void strAppend(char from[], char to[])
{
    // First we need to find the end of char to[]
    int toPos= 0;

    while (to[toPos] != '\0')
    {
        toPos++;
    }

    // Now that we have that, we can append
    int fromPos = 0; // Start at the beginning of from array.

    while (from[fromPos] != '\0')
    {
        to[toPos] = from[fromPos];
        toPos++;
        fromPos++;
    }

    toPos++;
    to[toPos] = '\0'; // Add null terminator
}

/**
 * Add an additional word to a sentence.
 * 
 * @param from
 * @param to
 */
void strAddWord(char from[], char to[])
{
    char space[2] = " ";
    strAppend(space, to);

    strAppend(from, to);
}

/*******************************************************************************
 * Card
 ******************************************************************************/

const int suits = 4; 
const int suitStrSize = 9;

const int ranks = 13;
const int rankStrSize = 6;

const int cardsAmt = 52;
const int cardStrSize = 255;

const int locationStrSize = 10;

struct card
{
    char suit[suitStrSize];
    char rank[rankStrSize];
    int cvalue;
    char location[locationStrSize];
};

/**
 * Print Card
 * 
 * @param card
 */
void printCard(card card)
{
    cout << card.rank << " of " << card.suit << endl;
}

/**
 * Create a card with default values.
 * 
 * @return card
 */
card makeCard()
{
    card card;

    strCopy("suit", card.suit, suitStrSize);
    strCopy("rank", card.rank, rankStrSize);
    card.cvalue = 0;
    strCopy("location", card.location, locationStrSize);

    return card;
}

/**
 * Copy card
 * 
 * @param from
 * @param to
 */
void copyCard(card from, card to)
{
    cout << "2) Card Copy, from: "; printCard(from);

    to.cvalue = from.cvalue;
    strCopy(from.location, to.location, locationStrSize);
    strCopy(from.rank, to.rank, rankStrSize);
    strCopy(from.suit, to.suit, suitStrSize);

    cout << "3) Card Copy, to: "; printCard(to);
}

/*******************************************************************************
 * Player
 ******************************************************************************/

const int playerAmt = 4;
const int handAmt = 3;
const int nameStrSize = 55;

struct player
{
    char name[nameStrSize];
    int total;
    card hand[handAmt];
};

/**
 * Print player name
 * 
 * @param player
 */
void printPlayerName(player player)
{
    cout << player.name << endl;
}

/**
 * Print out player
 * 
 * @param player
 */
void printPlayer(player player)
{
    printPlayerName(player);

    for (int i = 0; i < handAmt; i++)
    {
        cout << "   ";
        printCard(player.hand[i]);
    }
}

/**
 * Load players from file
 * 
 * @param players
 */
void loadPlayers(player players[playerAmt])
{
    fstream file;
    file.open("players.txt");

    int playerPos;
    int playerElement;
    char name[255];
    char word[255];

    for (int i = 0; !file.eof(); i++)
    {
        playerPos = i/2;
        playerElement = i%2;

        strEmpty(word);
        file >> word;

        switch(playerElement)
        {
            case 0:
                strEmpty(name);
                strCopy(word, name, nameStrSize);
                break;
            case 1:
                strAddWord(word, name);
                strCopy(name, players[playerPos].name, nameStrSize);
                break;
        }
    }

    cout << "Players loaded.";
}

/**
 * Print players to screen
 * 
 * @param players
 */
void printPlayers(player players[playerAmt])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < playerAmt; i++)
    {
        cout << players[i].name << endl;
    }
}

/*******************************************************************************
 * Deck
 ******************************************************************************/

/**
 * Create deck to file.
 */
void createDeck()
{
    char suit[suits][suitStrSize] = {"Spades", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts"};
    char rank[ranks][rankStrSize] = {"Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", 
                                     "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", 
                                     "Queen", "King", "Ace"};

    // Let's create our deck.
    fstream deckfile;
    deckfile.open("deck.txt", ios::trunc|ios::in|ios::out);

    int suitCounter = 0;
    for (int n = 0; n < cardsAmt; n++)
    {       
        // Card names
        deckfile << rank[n%ranks] << " ";
        deckfile << suit[suitCounter] << " ";

        int currentCard = (n%13) + 2;

        // Scores
        if (currentCard <= 10) {
            deckfile << (n%13) + 2 << " ";
        } else if (currentCard == 14) { // Ace
            deckfile << 11 << endl;
        } else {
            deckfile << 10 << " ";
        }

        if (n%ranks == ranks - 1) // If you're finished with the rank
        {
            suitCounter++;
        }
    }

    deckfile.close();

    cout << "Deck Created.";
}

/**
 * Load deck from file.
 * 
 * @param deck
 */
void newDeck(card deck[cardsAmt])
{
    fstream file;
    file.open("deck.txt");

    int deckPos;
    int fileElement;

    for (int i = 0; !file.eof(); i++)
    {        
        deckPos = i/3;
        fileElement = i%3;

        switch (fileElement)
        {
            case 0: 
                file >> deck[deckPos].rank;
                break;
            case 1: 
                file >> deck[deckPos].suit;
                break;
            case 2: 
                file >> deck[deckPos].cvalue;
                break;
        }
    }

    file.close();

    cout << "Fresh deck loaded.";
}

/**
 * Print the deck.
 * 
 * @param deck
 */
void printDeck(card deck[cardsAmt])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < cardsAmt; i++)
    {
        printCard(deck[i]);
    }
}

/**
 * Copy deck
 * 
 * @param from
 * @param to
 */
void copyDeck(card from[cardsAmt], card to[cardsAmt])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < cardsAmt; i++)
    {
        cout << "1) Deck Copy, from: "; printCard(from[i]);
        copyCard(from[i], to[i]);
        cout << "4) Deck Copy, to: "; printCard(to[i]); cout << endl;
    }
}

/**
 * Shuffle deck
 * 
 * @param deck
 */
void shuffleDeck (card deck[cardsAmt], card shuffled[cardsAmt])
{
    srand(time(NULL)); // Seed rand();

    copyDeck(deck, shuffled);

    // Shuffle
    for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
    {               
        swap(shuffled[rand()%cardsAmt], shuffled[rand()%cardsAmt]);
    }

    cout << "Deck shuffled.";
}

/**
 * Save deck to file
 * 
 * @param deck
 */
void saveDeck(card deck[cardsAmt])
{
    // Write shuffled deck to file
    fstream save;
    save.open("saved.txt", ios::trunc|ios::in|ios::out);

    for (int i = 0; i < cardsAmt; i++)
    {
        save << deck[i].rank << " of " << deck[i].suit << endl;
    }
    save.close();

    cout << "Deck saved.";
}

/*******************************************************************************
 * Game operations
 ******************************************************************************/

void deal(player players[playerAmt], card deck[cardsAmt])
{
    int dealAmt = playerAmt * handAmt;
    int playerCnt;
    int handCnt;

    for (int i = 0; i < dealAmt; i++)
    {
        playerCnt = i/3;
        handCnt = i%3;

        players[playerCnt].hand[handCnt] = deck[i];
    }

    cout << "Cards dealt.";
}

/**
 * Print hands
 * 
 * @param players
 */
void printHands(player players[playerAmt])
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < playerAmt; i++)
    {
        printPlayer(players[i]);
    }
}

/**
 * Print menu.
 */
void printMenu()
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Menu:" << endl;
    cout << "  1 - Show menu" << endl;
    cout << "  2 - Show Deck" << endl;
    cout << "  3 - Shuffle Deck" << endl;
    cout << "  4 - Save Deck" << endl;
    cout << "  5 - Reset Deck" << endl;
    cout << "  6 - Deal" << endl;
    cout << "  7 - Show players" << endl;
    cout << "  8 - Show hands" << endl;
    cout << "  0 - Exit" << endl;
}

/*******************************************************************************
 * Let's play
 ******************************************************************************/

/**
 * Lets do work
 * 
 * @return int
 */
int main() 
{   
    createDeck(); 
    cout << endl;

    // Let's create our deck.
    card deck[cardsAmt];
    newDeck(deck); 
    cout << endl;

    // Card positions
    card shuffled[cardsAmt];
    card discard[cardsAmt];
    card stockPile[cardsAmt];

    shuffleDeck(deck, shuffled);

    printDeck(shuffled);

    return 0;

    // Now our players
    player players[playerAmt];
    loadPlayers(players);
    cout << endl;

    cout << endl << "Welcome! Let's play." << endl;

    // Give them a menu
    printMenu(); 
    cout << endl;

    do
    {
        int input;
        cin >> input;

        switch (input)
        {
            case 0: return 0;
            case 1: printMenu(); break;
            case 2: printDeck(deck); break;
            case 3: shuffleDeck(deck, shuffled); break;
            case 4: saveDeck(deck); break;
            case 5: newDeck(deck); break;
            case 6: deal(players, deck); break;
            case 7: printPlayers(players); break;
            case 8: printHands(players); break;
            default:
                cout << "Unknown option " << input ;
                break;
        }

        cout << endl << endl;

    } while (true); 
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: That's an awful lot of code for what seems like a simple problem. Are you sure that you can't trim it down any more, leaving only the relevant parts that reproduce the bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this function:

```
void copyCard(card from, card to)
```

the from and to parameters are passed by value, so any changes you make inside the function will not be reflected in the calling function.

The easiest change would be to change the to parameter to pass by reference:

```
void copyCard(card from, card &to)
```

Note: you probably haven't learned references yet. They are worth looking up though and are easier to understand than pointers.

Also note: there are efficiency reasons to use a reference on the `from` parameter too, but it isn't part of your current problem.